# If anyone leaves me

Tags: riddle

> If anyone leaves me, I don't leave him.
>
> But if I leave once, I will not return.

What am I?

Comment: Sounds like the overly attached girlfriend is awaken from the addiction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be

> a secret?

If anyone leaves me, I don't leave him.

> If someone forgets a secret, it remains still.

But if I leave one, I will not return.

> Once a secret is revealed, it is no longer a secret.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you might be

> Hair

If anyone leaves me, I don't leave him.

> After having a haircut, hair normally grows back.

But if I leave once, I will not return.

> Once somebody starts going bald (through aging) their hair tends not to return.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is

> a legacy

If anyone leaves me, I don't leave him. But if I leave once, I will not return.

> After leaving a legacy behind, it will stay attached to you until you are forgotten.